# Unity, how do I pause the Audio in the Level?

Tags: unity, 2d, javascript, audio, menu

I wanna pause the Audio if I press the Pause Button also, I need help..

Pause Script:

```
#pragma strict

var pausemenu: GameObject;

public function pause() 
{
    pausemenu.SetActive(true);
    Time.timeScale = 0;

}

public function Resume () 
{
    pausemenu.SetActive(false);
    Time.timeScale = 1;
}

public function Restart ()
{
    Application.LoadLevel("IntroScene");
    Time.timeScale = 1;
}

public function MainMenu ()
{
    Application.LoadLevel("string");
}

public function Quit ()
{
    Application.Quit();
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to read our [help]; your last several questions have been some combination of unclear, asking about basic programming process, or asking for help debugging a vague problem in your code. These sorts of questions aren't a good fit for this site and are better asked on someplace like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net) or edited to be more focused and clear.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but i just wanted to pause the AudioSource if I press the Pause button, what information do I have to write in here too ?

Comment: @JoshPetrie I think this question is perfectly clear.

Comment: @NewmakerCompany Most of your questions (recently) seem to be of the form "I want to do <vague thing>, here's <some code>." This is problematic in general because generally there are *many* ways to interpret the problem you're having getting from <some code> to accomplishing <vague thing>. The more details you provide about the context surrounding your problem, what you tried, and what *specific* issues you are having, the better.

Comment: @NewmakerCompany For example, is this question, is your problem that you don't know how to *tell* the audio system to stop processing audio? Is your problem that you don't know how to hook up a button's event handlers to the "pause/Resume" functions you wrote? Is your problem that you don't know how to call these pause/resume functions in response to a key press? Is your problem that you have a compiler or runtime error when you try? Is your problem that you get everything written so it *appears* to work and breakpoints hit but the audio still plays?

Comment: Oh well, thanks, im doing game development not that long, I am new but i will keep it in mind Josh :)

Answer (score 4):

Call [`AudioListener.pause = true`](http://unity3dforge.com/documentation/ScriptReference/AudioListener-pause.html) in function `pause` and then [`AudioListener.pause = false`](http://unity3dforge.com/documentation/ScriptReference/AudioListener-pause.html) in function `Resume`. While the audio listener is paused, the whole sound system will be essentially frozen. When you set the paused state to false again, the audio system will resume playing as if nothing had happened.

If you have some sounds which you still want to play during pause (audio feedback from your pause menu, for example), set [`ignoreListenerPause = true`](http://unity3dforge.com/documentation/ScriptReference/AudioSource-ignoreListenerPause.html) on the `AudioSource`s of these sounds.